# Compute three-dimensional integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

${\int\int\int}zdxdydz$ over $M$, where $M = [x,y], x \ge 0, y\ge 0, z\ge \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2x.$I guess that $0  \le x \le 2, 0 \le z$, but I have no idea how to guess $y \le f(x)$ and $z \le g(x,y)$ for integration. Please, do not refer to geometrical entities; I need to understand how can I guess those $f,g$ algebraically, not by imagining 3D image (which I can't imagine).

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the equation for $z$. As you said it also implies $z\geq0$ since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq0$. It restricts $z\leq\sqrt{2x-(x^2+y^2)}$. That upper bound restricts $y\leq \sqrt{2x-x^2}$. The integral $$\int_{\sqrt{x^z+y^2}}^{\sqrt{2x-(x^2+y^2)}} zdz=[1/2z^2]=x-x^2-y^2$$
Then $$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}x-x^2-y^2 dy=\sqrt{2x-x^2}(x-x^2)-1/3(\sqrt{2x-x^2})^3$$

etc.

Comment: How does it restrict $y$? I did it that way: $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2x \to x^2 + y^2 + x^2 + y^2 \le 2x \to 2(x^2 + y^2) \le 2x \to y^2 \le x - x^2$$, but it gives me $\sqrt{x - x^2}$, not $\sqrt{2x - x^2}$.

Comment: @DarkArchon - sorry I may have made a mistake. Please take my answer as a hint only.